# Where did Kale get the grenades from?

Tags: plot-explanation, white-house-down

You see in ***White House Down***  that the White house has been taken into siege.
**Kale** has been trapped inside but not taken hostage and manages to save the **President Sawyer** from certain death.

My question is:

**Where did Kale get the grenades from and how long did he have them for?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Kale and the President take down a couple of bad guys in the White House residence...one of which in the kitchen, they grab their munitions.

After they kill the guy in the kitchen the President leaves the room for a few seconds and returns with the grenades, saying.

> Look what I found, Merry Christmas.

[image]